# How to chose a random CSV row starting with a certain letter?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in with two columns, the first one has a single letter code (like 'M' or 'B') and the second column has a URL. It's worth noting that there are many rows which have the same code. The bit I'm stuck on is choosing a random row which starts with a letter which the user has input.

So, for example, if the user had input the letter 'C',  then I want python to choose a random row beginning with 'C' and return the second column. Is this something that can be done or is it something horrifically complicated?

Comment: How big is the CSV? If it'd be fine to completely load into memory, a `dict` would be a good path.

Comment: Oh it's a tiny one, probably about 10-20 rows

Comment: Can you provide a sample CSV file..

Answer (score 1):

```
import easygui
import csv
import random

path = easygui.fileopenbox()
#print(path)
f = open(path, 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(f,dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
count=0
list1=[]
list2=[]

for row in reader:
    if(row[0]=='C'):
        list2.append(row)

chosen_row = random.choice(list(list2))
print(chosen_row[1])
```

You can use this code to select the log file and print the second column if only first column is equal to C. I have used a csv file which has this data below.

Input: trial.csv

```
B   url1
M   url2
C   url3
C   url4
C   url5
```

and got url3/url4/url5 anyone as output as it is random

Output:

```
url3
```

Comment: Doesn't address the desired randomness.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the CSV is relatively small, this is best done by loading the CSV into a `dict` and using `random.choice(...)` to choose a value to return to the user.

```py
import random

codes = {} # key: code, value: list of urls

# Load CSV into `codes`
with open("something.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        code, url = line.split(",")
        if code not in codes:
            codes[code] = []
        codes[code].append(url)

# Handle user input
input_code = input("Code: ")
print(random.choice(codes[input_code]))
```

Comment: Where is it given that the CSV is relatively small and why is reading it all into a `dict` the best way to do it?

Comment: @martineau OP stated "Oh it's a tiny one, probably about 10-20 rows" in a comment